# Detect Zombie at runtime

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, weak-references, nszombie

Is there a way to find a Zombie at runtime in objective-c?
I'm looking for a way to prevent an object to call a method on a zombie, is there any way to detect one without making the app crash?
I do know about weak reference under ARC iOS5 and common sense programming practice.
I was thinking that a way could be asking the object size (I know that maybe "inside" there are just reference) but if the object still exist it should give a value, if it doesn't probably just the single pointer size. 
Using `malloc_size(pointerToObject)`

Could it work?

UPDATE:
I do know how to run Instruments for Zombies detection

Comment: You could just call `brains()`, but you may end up with a bunch of `umbrellaCorporation` entries in your stack trace.

Comment: lol probably it would mean that I get the T-Virus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Andrea is asking how to run instruments to detect zombies, I think she wants to guard against calling a dealloced instance at runtime.  I'm not sure what malloc size will return in this case.  I think anything you come up with short of what they've done with NSZombies (which is to never truly free instances) will be gimicky and only work part of the time.  I think your best best is the boring old diligent programming and profiling with instruments to guard against making these calls rather than trying to catch the error at runtime.

Comment: Hi rooftop, you are right, I'm NOT looking about how to run an instruments session. I made few tests and I'd love to more, but it seems to work, in most cases but I still didn't get the rule. malloc_size return a value that is 0 if the object is deallocated, but not always I need to understand that rule. Probably the most effective solution will be use a proxy object that forward methods for any object that I need to "zeroing" . But I'm looking for a fast solution.

Comment: Well the malloc_size function has not a predictable behavior, using a Proxy could be a solution, but good programming rules are always the best[link]http://borkware.com/rants/agentm/elegant-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

Try running the application with Instruments, and select the "Zombies" template.

Answer (score 0):

On the scheme menu (upper left, next to run/stop).  Select "Edit Scheme...".   A sheet will appear.  Select the Run/Debug scheme there.  Select the "Diagnostics" tab on the center pane.  Check Zombies.